# Remove an attribute from an arrayList()

Tags: java, arraylist

As stated in the title how can I remove an attribute from an `arrayList`,
my method is like this :

```
public boolean removeBorrower(String libraryNumber)
```

I basically have to check if the parameters in this method is equals to the attribute if yes then remove the borrower according to that.

Here is my code :

```
import java.util.*;
/**
* Write a description of class BorrowerList here.
* 
* @author xxxxxx 
* @version 08/11/2015
*/
public class BorrowerList
{
    private ArrayList<Borrower> borrowers;

    public BorrowerList()
    {
        borrowers = new ArrayList<Borrower>();
    }

    public void addBorrowers(Borrower borrower)
    {
        borrowers.add(borrower);
    }

    public void getAllBorrowers()
    {   
        for(Borrower borrower : borrowers)
        {
            borrower.printBorrowerDetails();
        }
    } 

    public void getBorrower(int borrowerEntry)
    {
        if(borrowerEntry < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Negative entry :" + borrowerEntry);
        }
        else if(borrowerEntry < getNumberOfBorrowers())
        {
            Borrower borrower = borrowers.get(borrowerEntry);
            borrower.printBorrowerDetails();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No such entry :" + borrowerEntry);
        }
    } 

    public int getNumberOfBorrowers()
    {
        return borrowers.size();
    }

    public void removeBorrower(int borrowerEntry)
    {
        if(borrowerEntry < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Negative entry :" + borrowerEntry);
        }
        else if(borrowerEntry < getNumberOfBorrowers())
        {
            borrowers.remove(borrowerEntry);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No such entry :" + borrowerEntry);
        }
    }

    public boolean removeBorrower(String libraryNumber)
    {
        borrowers.remove(libraryNumber);
    }

    public int search(String libraryNumber)
    {
        int index = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        while(index < borrowers.size() && !found)
        {
            Borrower borrower = borrowers.get(index);
            if(borrower.getLibraryNumber().equals(libraryNumber))
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                index++;
            }
        }
        if (index < borrowers.size())
        {
            return index;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Edited :

Here is the code of the borrower class itself

```
/**
* Write a description of class Borrower here.
* 
* @author xxxxxx
* @version 08/11/2015
*/
public class Borrower
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String libraryNumber;
    private int noOfBooks;
    private Address address;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Borrower.
     * The number of books should be set to 1.
     * 
     * @param firstName The Borrower's first name 
     * @param lastName The Borrower's last name
     * @param lNumber The Borrower's library number
     * @param street The Borrower's street
     * @param town The Borrower's town
     * @param postcode The Borrower's postcode
     */
     public Borrower(String fName, String lName, String lNumber, 
                String street, String town, String postcode)
    {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        libraryNumber = lNumber;
        noOfBooks = 1;        
        address = new Address(street, town, postcode);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Borrower.
     * The number of books on loan should should be set to
     * the supplied vale.
     * 
     * @param fName The Borrower's first name 
     * @param lName The Borrower's last name
     * @param lNumber The Borrower's library number
     * @param numberOfBooks The initial book borrow
     * @param street The Borrower's street
     * @param town The Borrower's town
     * @param postcode The Borrower's postcode
     */
     public Borrower(String fName, String lName, String lNumber, int       numberOfBooks, 
                String street, String town, String postcode)
     {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        libraryNumber = lNumber;
        noOfBooks = numberOfBooks;         
        address = new Address(street, town, postcode);
     }


    /**
     * Get the Borrower's first name
     * 
     * @return the Borrower's first name
     */
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Borrower's last name
     * 
     * @return the Borrower's last name
     */
     public String getLastName()
     {
        return lastName;
     }

    /**
     * Get the Borrower's library Number
     * 
     * @return the Borrower's library number
     */
     public String getLibraryNumber()
    {
        return libraryNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of books on loan
     * 
     * @return the number of books on loan
     */
    public int getNoOfBooks()
    {
        return noOfBooks;
    }

    /**
     * Print out the Borrower's details to the console window
     * 
     */
    public void printBorrowerDetails()
    {
        System.out.println( firstName + " " + lastName 
                       + "\n" + address.getFullAddress()
                       + "\nLibrary Number: " + libraryNumber
                       + "\nNumber of loans: " + noOfBooks);
    }     



    /**
     * Increase the bumber of books on loan by 1
     * 
     */
    public void borrowBook()
    {
        noOfBooks = noOfBooks + 1;
        System.out.println("Books on loan: " + noOfBooks);        
    }

    /**
     * Increase the bumber of books on loan by a given number
     * 
     * @param number of new loans to add to total
     */
    public void borrowBooks(int number)
    {
        noOfBooks = noOfBooks + number;
        System.out.println("Books on loan: " + noOfBooks);        
    }

    /**
     * Return a book
     * 
     */
    public void returnBook ()
    {
        noOfBooks = noOfBooks - 1 ;
        System.out.println("Books on loan: " + noOfBooks);        
    }

    /**
     * Return the Borrower's address
     * 
     * @return the Borrower's address
     */
    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address.getFullAddress();
    }

    /**
     * Change the Borrower's address
     * 
     * @param street the street
     * @param town the town
     * @param postcode the postcode
     */
    public void setAddress(String street, String town, String postcode)
    {
        address.setFullAddress(street, town, postcode);
    }

    /**
     * Print out Borrower's address
     */
    public void printAddress()
    {
        address.printAddress();
    }

} // end class
```

Comment: Following link will be helpful. [Remove method arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520808/how-to-remove-specific-object-from-arraylist)

Comment: Could you please post the source of the `Borrower` class as well?

Comment: The borrower class has been added Shark

Answer (score 2):

As per the [`JavaDoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-):

> public boolean remove(Object o)
>
> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
>   if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is
>   unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i
>   such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an
>   element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified
>   element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the
>   call).

Which essentially means that `borrowers.remove(libraryNumber);` will work if and only if you have some `Borrower` object which is equal to that string. Unless you have added an override to the `equals` method in your `Borrower` class, it is unlikely that this will ever work. Thus, you have two options:

1. Override the `equals` (and for good practice, the `hashcode()`) methods within your `Borrower` class such that two borrower items are considered equal if they have the same `libraryNumber`.
2. The second option would be to use an `iterator` to go through your `Borrower` items stored within `borrower` and use the iterator's `remove` method to delete the objects which have the same property values.

As a side note, although the first approach might be more elegant for some, caution must be taken since in your particular scenario, `Borrower` objects might not be equal just because they have the same `libraryNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean removeBorrower(String libraryNumber)
{
    boolean retVal = false;
    if(borrowers.contains(libraryNumber))
    {
       retVal = borrowers.remove(libraryNumber);
    } 
    return retVal;
}
```

Something like this perhaps? I know it's a long round-about way of doing things, since the easiest way would be

```
public boolean removeBorrower(String libraryNumber)
{
       return borrowers.remove(libraryNumber);
}
```

But perhaps I don't quite understand what's the problem you're having?

Comment: This wont work. He has to override equals and hashcode

Comment: Yep, I just re-read the opening post and figured out that the custom `Borrower` class probably doesn't have a good implementation of `equals()` and subsequently `hashCode()` with special attention on `equals()`

Feel free to post a better implementation @Knu8

Comment: The borrower class has been added :)