# Remove a Listener from a List of Listeners

Tags: java, android, list, listener

I have a function that add **custom listeners** to the same trigger event.

So the same event can trigger multiple listeners, this is working.
What I would like is: if I have 3 listeners (for example) be able to remove just one of then and let the other two working.

This is my function to add events, they are in a `Map<String, CustomListener>` variable.

```
void addEventListener(String eventName, EventListener eventListener) {
    List<eventListener> eventListenerList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (eventListenerMap.containsKey(eventName)) {
        eventListenerList = eventListenerMap.get(eventName);
    }
    Objects.requireNonNull(eventListenerList).add(eventListener);
    eventListenerMap.put(eventName, eventListenerList);
}
```

And this is my function to remove

```
void removeEventListener(String eventName, EventListener eventListener) {
    if (eventListenerMap.containsKey(eventName)) {
        List<InsEventListener> eventListenerList = eventListenerMap.get(eventName);
        assert eventListenerList != null;
        eventListenerList.remove(eventListener);

        eventListenerMap.put(eventName, eventListenerList);
    }
    else {
        Log.w("Remove Event Listener:", "Event not found");
    }
}
```

As you can see in the image below, it recognise the same class with the same lamba address, but it won't remove.

[image]

Obs: all the listeners are called in the same function in the same place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `eventListenerList.remove(eventListener.getClass());` isn't removing anything. You aren't suppose to remove your listeners by their class, but by index or by a method that distinguishes them one from another. 
If you checked the `remove()` return value you would get false, which means the parameter wasn't in that list. [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)).

> In general an object can be removed in two ways from an `ArrayList` (or generally any List), by index (remove(int)) and by object (remove(Object)). [reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8520835/10470378)

**What you need to do:**

Add an equals(Object) method to your `EventListener` class. That will allow you to do `eventListenerList.remove(eventListener)` to identify the correct object.

I think the simplest thing to do is to add a name or id attribute to your Parent class that will be unique between all of your listeners, and override equals that checks for those attributes.

You can easily generate `equals(object)` method with Android Studio IDE, press Ctrl + O and choose the equals method.

**EDIT:**

I suggest two options for handling IDs for your listeners:

1. Generate the ID yourself in `addEventListener` and return it to the caller, 
   store the listener in a map instead of list, the key is the ID. When someone 
   wants to remove a listener, he will send the generated ID and you will remove 
   it from the Event's listeners map.
2. Generate the ID yourself in `addEventListener` and save it in an `EventListener` ID attribute that cannot be changed by anyone else. Then, to remove a specific listener, you only need to implement an `equals` methods that checks the ID attribute.

Comment: You are right, .getclass was just a test that I forgot to remove. But without, just passing the listener object, don't work too. I will check this .equals option. The ID option is not good because it will be used for other developers who sound not worry about it. But thanks for the inside.